# passport js not adding user to the session - req.user undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I just wanna point out that I'm new to backend stuff, so I have an **expressjs** server using **passport** for authentication and mongodb. but I can't make it serialize my user into the session therefore I can never persist the user if I refresh my page.

when I do `console.log(req.user);`I always get **undefined**

The frontend is running react code separately and makes HTTP requests to this server.

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config()
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const cors = require('cors')
const connectDb = require("./config/dbConnection");
const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorHandler");
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport")


const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);


/**
 * -------------- GENERAL SETUP ----------------
 */

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express()
connectDb();
app.use(cors());
app.use(errorHandler);
app.use(express.json());





/**
 * -------------- SESSION SETUP ----------------
 */

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  collection: "sessions",
});


app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // Equals 1 day (1 day * 24 hr/1 day * 60 min/1 hr * 60 sec/1 min * 1000 ms / 1 sec)
    }
}));


/**
 * -------------- PASSPORT AUTHENTICATION ----------------
 */

 require('./config/passport')

app.use(passport.session());
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.session);
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
});

/**
 * -------------- ROUTES ----------------
 */

app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/userRoutes"));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
  });
```

**userControlers**

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const passport = require("passport");


//@desc Register a user
//@route POST /api/users/register
//@access public
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  if (!username || !email || !password) {
    res.status(400);

  }
  const userAvailable = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (userAvailable) {
    res.status(400);

  }

  //Hash password
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  console.log("Hashed Password: ", hashedPassword);
  const user = await User.create({
    username,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword,
  });

  console.log(`User created ${user}`);
  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({ _id: user.id, username: user.username, email: user.email });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
  }
});




//@desc login user
//@route POST /api/users/login
//@access public
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'User is authenticated' });
});


//@desc userAuth
//@route POST /api/users/checkAuth
//@access public
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'User is loged in' });
  }else{
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'You must be logged in to access this resource.' });
  }
};


//@desc userLogout
//@route POST /api/users/logout
//@access public
const logoutUser = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    req.logout();
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'User is loged out' });
  }else{
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unable to logout User.' });
  }
};



module.exports = { isAuthenticated, registerUser, loginUser, logoutUser};
```

**userRoutes**

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const {
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  isAuthenticated,
  logoutUser
} = require("../controlers/userControler");


const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", registerUser);
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), loginUser);
router.get("/checkAuth", isAuthenticated);
router.post("/logout",logoutUser);


module.exports = router;
```

**passport**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../models/userModel');

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    { usernameField: 'email' },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' });
        }

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (!isMatch) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' });
        }

        return done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error);
  }
});

module.exports = passport;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try replacing id with { id } in `passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done)...`

Comment: I just did, but got the same result, undefined for req.user and no user added to the session